My Eclipse keeps crashing everytime I shutdown and restart my laptop
Every time I start my laptop and start Eclipse I am getting below error.

I have to reinstall the eclipse every time and then it starts working fine. But it is very painful to work like this as I need to then install all the plugins as well from the scratch which takes a lot of time.
Can someone please tell me how can I fix this issue please?
I removed once all the java,jdk and eclipse workspace too but it's still the same.

The Java VM with which you run your Eclipse IDE for Eclipse Committers 2024-03 is crashing. It is an Oracle Java VM installed on your system, but your question does not tell which one exactly. It is highly recommended to use the JDK that is shipped with the Eclipse JDK rather than a JRE/JDK installed on your system.

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

Thanks. Could you please tell me how can I know this Oracle Java VM which is installed in my system? And where can I check the JDK that is shipped with Eclipse in my system please?

What do you get for "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe" -version? In the Eclipse Installer, in the Java 17+ VM drop-down, choose JRE 17.0.11 - https://download.eclipse.org/justj/jres/17/updates/release/latest.

When I go to this C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe path,it's opening a new window and shutting down automatically. What could be the issue here please?

On the command line (Terminal) run "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe" -version and tell what it prints.

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath>java.exe -version
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath>
No output with this command,is there anything missing in my system please?

As already said, it is highly recommended to run Eclipse with the Java with which it is shipped instead of a Java version that is installed on your system. Can you run the following Eclipse IDE? https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/2024-06/R/eclipse-jee-2024-06-R-win32-x86_64.zip
